# Decryption fails for AES CBC 128 bit using OpenSSL using the EVP API in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

Hello I have a set of data vectors `std::vector<uint8_t>` I need to encrypt using AES CBC 128, and I am trying to use OpenSSL AES CBC 128 using the EVP API for this. However for some reason I cannot get the data to decrypt. As shown in the console output:

````sh
$ ./a.out 
Original data: b25f6a3f71a9285
Data before encryption b25f6a3f71a9285
Data after encryption bceb55ccb26d83b02d63ff785e538af000000000
Data was encrypted moving on to decryption
Origninal data after decryption b25f6a3f71a9285
data after decryption e7fc6fdb4f9aa50cfb46764c04010fb000000000
[Failure] we failed data is not decrypted```
````

However, I cannot find where in my code I have made the mistake.

Here is a bare minimum example I have been using:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cassert>

#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <utility>
#include <sstream>

void print_data(const std::vector<uint8_t> data)
{
    std::stringstream ss; 
    for (const auto& elm : data)
    {
        ss << std::hex << (int)elm; 
    }
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl; ; 
}

std::vector<uint8_t> generate_data(size_t size)
{
    srand(static_cast<uint32_t>(time(0)));

    std::vector<uint8_t> data(size);
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), rand);
    return data; 
}

void aes_128_cbc_init_cryptert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX* crypter_context, const std::string& key, bool decrypter=false)
{
    unsigned char aes_key[key.size()];
    strcpy((char*) aes_key, key.c_str()); 

    std::vector<uint8_t> iv(AES_BLOCK_SIZE, 0);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(crypter_context);
    if (decrypter)
    {
        EVP_DecryptInit_ex(crypter_context, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, aes_key, iv.data());
    }
    else
    {
        EVP_EncryptInit_ex(crypter_context, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, aes_key, iv.data());
    }

}


void encrypt(const std::string& key, std::vector<uint8_t>& data)
{

    // Maximum lenghter of cipher is data.sizE() + AES_BLOCK_SIZE - 1 
    int cipher_length = data.size() + 1 + AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    int final_length = 0;
    int data_length = static_cast<int>(data.size()); 

    std::vector<uint8_t> cipher(cipher_length, 0);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX en;
    aes_128_cbc_init_cryptert(&en, key);

    EVP_EncryptUpdate(&en, cipher.data(), &cipher_length, data.data(), data_length);

    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&en, cipher.data()+cipher_length, &final_length);
    data = cipher;    
}

void decrypt(const std::string& key, std::vector<uint8_t>& data)
{
    // Will always be smaller that encrypted data
    int out_length = data.size();
    int final_length = 0;
    std::vector<uint8_t> out(out_length);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX en;
    aes_128_cbc_init_cryptert(&en, key, true);
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(&en, out.data(), &out_length, data.data(), data.size());
    EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(&en, out.data()+out_length, &final_length);
    data = out; 
}


int main(void)
{
    std::string key = "7LVQ2YOYWI4AQNYC";

    std::vector<uint8_t> org_data = generate_data(8);

    std::cout << "Original data: "; 
    print_data(org_data);
    auto data = org_data;
    std::cout << "Data before encryption ";
    print_data(data); 
    encrypt(key, data);

    std::cout << "Data after encryption ";
    print_data(data); 
    if (data == org_data)
    {
        std::cout << "Data was not encrypted" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Data was encrypted moving on to decryption" << std::endl; 
    }

    decrypt(key, data);

    std::cout << "Origninal data after decryption ";
    print_data(org_data);
    std::cout << "data after decryption ";
    print_data(data);

    if (data == org_data)
    {
        std::cout << "[Success] Data was decrypted" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "[Failure] we failed data is not decrypted" << std::endl;
        return - 1; 
    }
}
```

I am think it is because I am doing something wrong with either size of input and output to decrypt or the initalisation of the "decrypter" it self, but I have been unable to confirm this. I have been working of, of this example: https://github.com/saju/misc/blob/master/misc/openssl_aes.c

Comment: *Note*: Since you are using an IV of all zeroes and the data to be encrypted is at most the same length as the block size, essentially you are encrypting using ECB mode.

Comment: The shown code ignores `final_length`. That's at least one flaw.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ignores it ?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik from what I can tell with vectors, should I be able to ignore it?

Comment: Output parameters are not something that mean nothing. Otherwise they wouldn't be there in the first place. There's a reason for the output parameter. See OpenSSL's documentation.